# Converting chart element into an image returning empty image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I have some data I am retrieving from an external endpoint that I then render to a chart using apex charts. As I want to be able to download this chart into a PDF, I am using jsPDF to try and generate a PDF.

However, as it is not an image, I cannot use addImage to add it in. When I use addHTML it only adds the raw data and not the chart itself. So, I am trying to convert the chart to an image using html2canvas but there is an error somewhere. Although a PDF is generated, there is no image on that file although the function is run (tested using basic console.log calls). Here is my code for the conversion:

```
  function download() {
    let input = window.document.getElementsByName("graph");

    html2canvas(input).then(canvas => {
      const img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      const pdf = new jsPDF();
      pdf.addImage(
        img, 
        "png");
      pdf.save("chart.pdf");
      })
```

The chart itself is generated using this code:

```
 <Chart className="responseGraph1" id="graph" options={options}  series={series} type="area" width={'90%'} height={'80%'}/>
```

The data for this chart is generated from an endpoint and works as expected. My question is, am I using html2canvas wrong or is there something else going on here? I would appreciate any help/guidance.